# How to position background image inside table cell with padding

Tags: css

In application I have a few columns that can contain inline-editable values. For these cells, I want to display a pencil icon:

```
td.editable
{
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-image: url(pencil.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
```

This CSS is almost fine except... I would like to have a 2px space between cells border and image. Is is possible to achieve it with background image and CSS? If not, how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-save your BG image with a 2px transparent border and make the inputs 4px taller to accomodate the new height.

Comment: I thought about it, yet I wasn't sure it's the best solution. But if a person with 15.7k reputation thinks the same, it must be good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the background-position property with x% y%.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Mixing flexible widths with inflexible widths doesn't work so hot if you want the background placed relative to the right edge of the element, since the position marks where the top/left corner of the image is to be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table { border-spacing: 2px;}
```

Comment: the `border-spacing` property defines the distance between the table cells, so it won't affect a background image in an input inside a table cell

Comment: Yeah I know that, but he mentioned it above: "I would like to have a 2px space between cells border and image." So, this solve it.

Comment: nope :) it will make the cells to be farther from each other, but the background image will stick to the particular cell border without any space

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way? Add 2 pixels to the right of your pencil.png. You could screw around with background position but not worth the effort.